# How to store data from axios post in localstorage

Tags: javascript, axios

I have the problem that when i want to store data i got from a axios post in localstorage i only get a promise object when i get it from localstorage. I cant figure out what i have to do with it. Can someone help me ?

```
function login(email, password) {
  return axios.post('http://localhost:3001/users/login', {
    email: email,
    password: password,
  }).then(response => {
    return response.data.token
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

var t = login(email,password).then(data =>{
      localStorage.setItem('token1',data)
    })
    localStorage.setItem('token2',t)


    console.log('varT: '+t)
    console.log('token1: '+localStorage.getItem('token1'))
    console.log('token2: '+localStorage.getItem('token2'))
```

[image: Output]

Comment: You can't store `t` in localStorage. It only stores strings. Your console.log statements are outside the promise chain which is asynchronous. So they will run before the response is returned from login

Comment: My token is a string. Do i need to call value or something on the response ? @charlietfl

Comment: `setItem('token1', data)` should work. But do your console logging inside the `then()`  The other definitely won't work

Comment: How do i access then the local storage? @charlietfl

Comment: Same way you are doing now for `token1`

Comment: You're right. hmm i bet i already tried that but anyway thank you. Do you make a answer so i can close this question as solved ?@charlietfl